# Search a directory of .cab files

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I need to extract drivers from the HP CD that came with a P1006 printer. I don't want all the useless utilities from HP, JUST the drivers. When I thought I had what I needed to add the drivers to XP the install is prompting me for some .dll files I cannot find. I imagine these .dll's are in one of the several .cab files on the installation CD.

Any idea on how to search the contents of a directory of .cab files for a specific file or extension?

EDIT: Sorry, maybe I was ambiguous with my question. I know how to extract a .cab file but my problem is I have A LOT of them and don't know which one contains the file I need. I wanted something where I could type a search term in and it would go through each file for me and report back what it found. Just imagine if Windows Search searched .cab files instead of directories.

Comment: did you try downloading from the site, that way you do not need to mess with a CD?  maybe you have.. just a suggestion

Comment: @fady - The download file on HP is 163 MB and says contains the same information as the packaged CD. F it, I'm going to try anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran out of time to search for the drivers and so I had to give up. I used to .exe installer from HP to install the drivers. So incredibly frustrating but not worth the time.

Answer (score 3):

[**Universal Extractor**](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) can extract `.cab` files, and tons of other formats too!

[image]

Best of all, Universal Extractor is freeware.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) when I want to look inside archives or installers. It works with most formats including MSI. It is nice and clean, easy to use, and does not rely on external tools. It should work for you purposes.

However, if the drivers are for some bizarre reason *only* available inside an InstallShield/Inno/etc. installation, then you coulduse Universal Extract as John suggested, or look to other utilities like [Dragon Unpacker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dragonunpacker/) (or you could do it yourself with something like **i6comp**).

Answer (score 0):

Far Manager (http://www.farmanager.com/) can search a directory of .cab files very well.

Press Alt-F7 and put a checkmark next to 'Search in archives'.